# Image segmentation for composite delamination area

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

Part of a research project is to correctly measure the delamination area of a drilled hole, as shown in the picture. 
[image: DRILLED HOLE]

To achieve this, I need to manage to develop an image segmentation algorithm/method to identify the contours of the delamination area around the hole so that we can obtain a result similar to the picture below.

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Image based on this paper -> [Paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322977190_A_Digital_Image_Analysis_to_Evaluate_Delamination_Factor_after_Drilling_GFRP_Composites_using_a_Kevlar_Drill_Bit)

Attached image of delamination area.
[image: Delamination damaged area]

I'm working with python and openCV for the image processing tasks. So far, I've tried several methods like thresholds (THRESH_BINARY, THRESH_OTSU, calculation the mean pixel value of the picture and then apply thresholds...) in both grayscale images and in separated HSV channels. I've also tried cv2.equalizeHist(gray) but these methods only seem to segment the contour hole-composite workpiece (which is desirable to get hole diameter), but we mainly need to calculate damaged area.

What's the best approach to do a good delamination damage segmentation of this image?

```py
### IMAGES ARE RESIZED FOR BETTER VISUALIZATION IN SCREEN, BUT IMAGE PROCESSING OPERATIONS ARE DONE WITH NORMAL SIZE PICTURES ###

import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
imageRe = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
cv2.imshow('Hole Imported Picture.', imageRe)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#histogram calculation GRAY SCALED IMAGE
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.hist(gray.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()


imageRe = cv2.resize(gray,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
cv2.imshow('Gray scale image.', imageRe)


ecualized_img = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
cv2.imwrite('ecualized_img.jpg', ecualized_img)
imageRe = cv2.resize(ecualized_img,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
cv2.imshow('Ecualized image.', imageRe)

##################
img = gray
# global thresholding
ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  #Threshold set in 127 by default
# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# plot all the images and their histograms
images = [img, 0, th1,
          img, 0, th2,
          blur, 0, th3]
titles = ['Original Noisy Image','Histogram','Global Thresholding (v=127)',
          'Original Noisy Image','Histogram',"Otsu's Thresholding",
          'Gaussian filtered Image','Histogram',"Otsu's Thresholding"]

imageRe = cv2.resize(th1,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
cv2.imshow('Normal Thresholding image.', imageRe)

imageRe = cv2.resize(th2,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
cv2.imshow('Otsus Thresholding image.', imageRe)


for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(3,3,i*3+1),plt.imshow(images[i*3],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i*3]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(3,3,i*3+2),plt.hist(images[i*3].ravel(),256)
    plt.title(titles[i*3+1]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(3,3,i*3+3),plt.imshow(images[i*3+2],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i*3+2]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
###################

src = img
ddepth = cv2.CV_16S
kernel_size = 3

ecualized_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(ecualized_img, (3, 3), 0)
    # [reduce_noise]
    # Convert the image to grayscale
#src_gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # [convert_to_gray]
    # [laplacian]
    # Apply Laplace function
dst = cv2.Laplacian(ecualized_img, ddepth, ksize=3)
    # [laplacian]
    # [convert]
    # converting back to uint8
abs_dst = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dst)
    # [convert]
    # [display]
imageRe = cv2.resize(abs_dst,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
cv2.imshow('Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG)', imageRe)

#retVal, t = cv2.threshold(ecualized_img, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#t = cv2.threshold( ecualized_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU );
#imageRe = cv2.resize(t,None,fx=0.6,fy=0.6)
#cv2.imshow('Ecualized + THRESH_OTSU image.', imageRe)




cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you add an image showing what you consider as the damaged area in the picture you have attached?

Comment: I uploaded a new image highlighting the delamination area I need to segment for area measurement. I would totally appreciate if you could please help me with this or give me an approach to do this.